# What is the entry point of a Django app similar to main.py? Where do I set up parameters?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, dependency-injection, django-views

I want to set up some parameters and initialize the Injector object, because I want to use a dependency injection and singletons in my Django app.

Usually I do that in the main.py of my app but with Django I don't see where the first entry point of the application is when it runs. Where shoud I initialize the injector and pass it my views and services?

I have a view like this:

```
from uuid import UUID
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from Instruments.services import InstrumentsService
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from Instruments.services import InstrumentsService
from injector import singleton, inject


# Application views live here
@singleton
class InstrumentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @inject
    def __init__(self, instrument_service: InstrumentsService, **kwargs):
        self.instrument_service = instrument_service
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def list(self, request: HttpRequest):
        data = {}

        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.get_instruments()
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"Status": f"Error: {exc}"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                safe=False,
            )

    def create(self, request):
        instrument_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        data = {}

        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.add_instrument(instrument_data)
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, safe=False)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk: UUID = None):
        data = {}

        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.get_instrument_by_id(pk)
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"Status": f"Error: {exc}"},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                safe=False,
            )

    def update(self, request, pk: UUID = None):
        instrument_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        data = {}

        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.update_instrument_by_id(pk, instrument_data)
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"Status": f"Error: {exc}"},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                safe=False,
            )

    def destroy(self, request, pk: UUID = None):
        data = {}
        try:
            data = self.instrument_service.delete_instrument_by_id(pk)
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"Status": f"Error: {exc}"},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                safe=False,
            )
```

and a service like this:

```
import uuid
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.http.request import RAISE_ERROR, HttpRequest
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound, ValidationError
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import status
from Instruments.models import Instrument
from Instruments.serializers import InstrumentsSerializer
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from injector import inject, singleton


@singleton
class InstrumentsService:
    @inject
    def __init__(self, instruments: Instrument):
        self.instruments = instruments.objects.all()

    def get_instrument_by_id(self, id: uuid.UUID):
        try:
            instruments = get_object_or_404(self.instruments, pk=id)
            serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(instruments)

        except Instrument.DoesNotExist as exc:
            raise NotFound(f"No items where found with the given id {id}")

        return serializer.data

    def update_instrument_by_id(self, id: uuid.UUID, instrument_data: dict):
        try:

            instruments = get_object_or_404(self.instruments, pk=id)
            serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(instruments, data=instrument_data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()

            else:
                raise ValidationError(
                    "The data provided for updating an instrument are not valid"
                )

        except Instrument.DoesNotExist as exc:
            raise NotFound(f"No items where found with the given id {id}")

        self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
        return serializer.data

    def delete_instrument_by_id(self, id: uuid.UUID):
        try:

            instruments = get_object_or_404(self.instruments, pk=id)
            serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(instruments)
            instruments.delete()

        except Instrument.DoesNotExist as exc:
            raise NotFound(f"No items where found with the given id {id}")

        self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
        return serializer.data

    def get_instruments(self):
        serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(self.instruments, many=True)

        return serializer.data

    def add_instrument(self, instrument_data: Instrument):

        serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(data=instrument_data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
            raise ValidationError(
                "The data provided for registering a new instrument are not valid"
            )

        self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
        return serializer.data
```

where would someone inilialize the injector to create the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I made the dependency injection work the problem was not the injector it was the fact that in the `class InstrumentsService:` posted above I was trying to do :

```
def __init__(self, instruments: Instrument):
    self.instruments = instruments.objects.all()
```

but the object manager is not accesible for Django object thourgh objects (clas instances) but directly through the class. SO if I correct the `class InstrumentsService:` to this and also use this `django-injector` module [Django injector](https://pypi.org/project/django-injector/) everything works:

```
import uuid
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.http.request import RAISE_ERROR, HttpRequest
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound, ValidationError
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import status
from Instruments.models import Instrument
from Instruments.serializers import InstrumentsSerializer
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class InstrumentsService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()

    def get_instrument_by_id(self, id: uuid.UUID):
        try:
            instruments = get_object_or_404(self.instruments, pk=id)
            serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(instruments)

        except Instrument.DoesNotExist as exc:
            raise NotFound(f"No items where found with the given id {id}")

        return serializer.data

    def update_instrument_by_id(self, id: uuid.UUID, instrument_data: dict):
        try:

            instruments = get_object_or_404(self.instruments, pk=id)
            serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(instruments, data=instrument_data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()

            else:
                raise ValidationError(
                    "The data provided for updating an instrument are not valid"
                )

        except Instrument.DoesNotExist as exc:
            raise NotFound(f"No items where found with the given id {id}")

        self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
        return serializer.data

    def delete_instrument_by_id(self, id: uuid.UUID):
        try:

            instruments = get_object_or_404(self.instruments, pk=id)
            serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(instruments)
            instruments.delete()

        except Instrument.DoesNotExist as exc:
            raise NotFound(f"No items where found with the given id {id}")

        self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
        return serializer.data

    def get_instruments(self):
        serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(self.instruments, many=True)

        return serializer.data

    def add_instrument(self, instrument_data: Instrument):

        serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(data=instrument_data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
            raise ValidationError(
                "The data provided for registering a new instrument are not valid"
            )

        self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
        return serializer.data
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can look at [Django Applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/)

In you application folder, you probably have an `apps.py` file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyApp(AppConfig):

    def ready(self):
        # do stuff here
```

This is the entry point of your application.

**Edit**:

There is a project that already do that: [django-injector](https://github.com/blubber/django_injector)

Comment: thanks! that is useful but still how can I initialize the injector?